# Как получить линки из фрейма?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Как получить все ссылки с странице через расширения Chrome, включая ссылки фрейма?

Например на http://myip.ru

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0, max=links.length; i<max; i++) 
{
    console.log(links[i].href); 
}
```

Я получаю ссылки размещены на сайте, но не получаю из фрейма(ссылки обозревателя).

Как получить ссылки из баннера?

[image: как получить линки из банера ?]

**Обновление**

Попробовал приведенный в ответе код

```
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"), 
links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

frames.forEach(function (frame) {  
  var frameLinks = frame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('a') || [];
  links = links.concat(frameLinks);
});
```

Но появляется ошибка

> TypeError: frames.forEach is not a function

В чем может быть проблема?

**Обновление 2**

Собираю ссылки так:

```
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"), 
links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
frames = Array.prototype.slice.call(frames);
frames.forEach(function (frame) {  
  var frameLinks = frame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('a') || [];
   //links = links.concat(frameLinks);

  console.log(links);
  console.log(frameLinks);
});
```

Но ничего не получается.

Comment: взять HTML страницы и регулярными выражениями распарсить?

Comment: Браузер Chrome не поддерживает **forEach** !

Answer (score 1):

```
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"), 
links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

frames.forEach(function (frame) {  
  var frameLinks = frame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('a') || [];
  links = links.concat(frameLinks);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Из айфрейма с чужого домена не получится - политика безопасности.

Comment: т.е хром видит эту линку а расширения хрома не может ?  так по вашему получается ?